# The common solution of AX=0 and A^TX=0

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-rank

Suppose the only common solution is the zero vector,I wonder what can we say about $A\in \mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$.

I know if the only common solution is the zero vector,then the rank of
$\begin{pmatrix}A\\A^T\end{pmatrix}$ is $n$.